# Implementing google places autocomplete in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

Im creating an android app where im reusing the google places api to get the autocomplete function. I way i have succesfully implemented functionality is by using this code.

```
int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
...
try {
Intent intent =
        new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
// TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
// TODO: Handle the error.
}
```

This code is launched when the user clicks on a menu_button from a popupmenu in the firstscreen (mainscreen)

This code is able to do what i want it to do, but i dont know how to edit the fragment it creates. I want to set a hint thats different from "search" which is by default. The reason i used this code was because its able to create a sort of dialog or dim the background and creating the the autocompletefragment on top of the first screen which is what i want. Is there an another way to implement the autocomplete?

tl:dr
I want to use the google places autocomplete, and i want it to pop up like a dialog (Dim the first screen and the searchbar goes on top of the first screen).

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Use PlaceAutocompleteFragment, see here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/